# What are options for Storing large data in WKWebView IOS as Web SQL is not supported

Tags: ios, html, sqlite, wkwebview, web-sql

I have a Web SQL application which creates a database in browser and store data ranging from 5MB to 120MB. 
Loading this database the app fetches record executing queries and show result. 
This thing works good for Chrome browsers on all OS, safari on Mac. 
But as Web SQL is not supported in WKWebView is there any alternative I can try to store data ?
Anyone there to help ?